# Referencing the text input from within jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Given the following code, how can I reference the input that has autocomplete bound to it from within the `success()` function in the `$.ajax` call? Neither `$(this)` or `$e` work.

```
$('.parent-input').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/chunky/bacon",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        product_id: $('#product-id').val(),
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function(data){
        var resultCount = data.length;
        // I NEED TO REFERENCE .parent-input HERE
        response( data );
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui){
    addAssociatedProduct(ui.item.id, ui.item.value);
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Are there multiple elements of class `parent-input`? If not, why not just give it an id of `parent-input` instead, and reference it using the selector function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save a reference to `this.element` (`this.element` is a jQuery object so there's actually no need to wrap it in another jQuery call):

```
$('.parent-input').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var element = this.element; // <-- this.element is the input the widget is bound to.
    $.ajax({
      url: "/chunky/bacon",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        product_id: $('#product-id').val(),
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function(data){
        var resultCount = data.length;
        // element still refers to the input the widget is bound on.
        // for example:

        element.addClass("blue");

        response( data );
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui){
    addAssociatedProduct(ui.item.id, ui.item.value);
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're going to use `var element=this;`, you'll probably have to add the `context: element` parameter to the ajax call

Comment: @hughes: Actually I don't think you *have* to, but it would enable you to use `$(this)` inside of the success function of the AJAX call.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. In that case, does `element` become a global variable? Or is the success function within the scope of of `element`'s declaration? Or does all that not even matter in JS?

Comment: @hughes: No, `element` is scoped to the `source` function.

Comment: Excellent!  And I just found there is no need to declare the "element" variable, in the success handler can refer to $(this)[0].element